# Discord.JS getting "Expected a string primitive Received: | undefined" when registering command

Tags: discord, discord.js

i was trying to create a new slash command, i use a folder called commands and i require every file in that folder to register it

this is the command file:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, Client, CommandInteraction, CommandInteractionOptionResolver } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")

  async do(client, interaction, options) {
    const check = await interaction.reply({content: "Pinging...", fetchReply: true});
    const latency = check.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp;

    const pingEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(":ping_pong: Pong!")
      .setColor([40,40,38,255])
      .setTimestamp()
      .addFields(
        {name: "Bot Latency", value: `${latency}ms`, inline: true},
        {name: "API Latency", value: `${client.ws.ping}ms`, inline: true});
        

    await interaction.editReply({content: "", embeds: [pingEmbed]});
  }
};
```

when i try to load it i keep getting an Expected a string primitive error

i was expecting it to register the command successfully, but instead it keeps giving me an error, i tried everything on the guide what it said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is very simple and straightforward and if you would have reviewed the discord.js documentation, you would have known that slash commands need to have a description to register.

Therefore, add a `.setDescription()` below your .setName method and give it a description before trying again.